# ReactJS Login with redirect if authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to put together a simple login system with a Laravel backend.

I have:

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Login extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        // do something like setting default state
    }

    processSubmit(values) {
        // do something with the values
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="container mt-5">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-6">
                        <div className="card">
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h2 className="text-center font-weight-light mb-4">Sign into your account</h2>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

When successfully logged in, redirect to dashboard...

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return <div>

        </div>
    }

}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Login from '../containers/LogIn';
import CreateUsers from '../containers/CreateUsers';
import Dashboard from '../containers/Dashboard';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        };
    }

    userHasAuthenticated = authenticated => {
        this.setState({isAuthenticated: authenticated});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <NavBar />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/users/create" component={CreateUsers}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

How do I get it to redirect the user to the login page if they are not authenticated and same with if they are send them to the dashboard/home page?

Comment: You can consider creating a [PrivateRoute](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) component that can help with this auth workflow to redirect the user automatically to /login for example if they are not authenticated.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky This is awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `componentDidMount()` or `constructor()`, try doing a [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and see if your current session is active. In case it's active, set the session to be true by calling:

```
this.userHasAuthenticated(true);
```

Something like this might work:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  };

  fetch("/api/isUserLoggedIn")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    if (res == true) {
      this.userHasAuthenticated(true);
      // Redirect the user only if they are on the login page.
      // So the below code should be there only on the login component.
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  });
}
```

ps: This is how we do it in our app.

Comment: Where is the redirect?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky There's no redirect here at the moment. This sets the state and I am adding the redirect now.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Done. Added.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks, but the redirect doesn't work. When I load the page I get the true response but it doesn't send the user to the dashboard.

Comment: May need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

Comment: How do I implement that into what I'm doing? Sorry I am quite new to ReactJS.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Sorry I am getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'userHasAuthenticated' of undefined